# Custom dynamic shipping rate cost calculation in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I've set up a custom shipping method, i need to calculate shipping cost every time users get to the cart page.

It seems that `woocommerce_package_rates` action (where I calculate the custom shipping costs) runs only when user does click on a shipping method. This way the cart total is wrong most of the times, the worst is when the custom shipping method is already selected (user doesn't need to click it, so its cost doesn't update).

Is this the normal behavior of `woocommerce_package_rates` hook?

How to force `woocommerce_package_rates` to be **always** executed before displaying the cart totals?

**EDIT**

Here's some code i'm trying to hack with:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'force_shipping_calc', 1, 0 );
function force_shipping_calc() {
    foreach( WC()->session->get('shipping_for_package_0')['rates'] as $rate_id =>$rate) {
        // looking for the shipping method to recalc
        if($rate->method_id == 'flat_rate') {

            // mk1: set_shipping_total won't work, i'm using woocommerce < 3
            //WC()->cart->set_shipping_total( MY_calculate_shipping() );

            // mk2: doesn't work, "Indirect modification of overloaded property" 
            WC()->cart->totals['shipping_total'] = wc_format_decimal( MY_calculate_shipping(), wc_get_price_decimals() );

            // mk3: cart total nor shipping total affected (?!)
            WC()->cart->shipping_total = MY_calculate_shipping();

            // mk4: ... ?! work in progress...
    }
}

function MY_calculate_shipping() {
    return 99.99;
}


add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'fty_shipping_flat_rate_cost_calculation', 10, 2 );
function fty_shipping_flat_rate_cost_calculation($rates, $package) {
    foreach($rates as $rate_key => $rate_values) {

        $method_id = $rate_values->method_id;
        $rate_id = $rate_values->id;

        if ( 'flat_rate' === $method_id ){

            $dist_cost  =   MY_calculate_shipping();

            $price_excl_tax = $rates[$rate_id]->cost + $dist_cost;
            $rates[$rate_id]->cost =  number_format($price_excl_tax, 2);

            $tax_keys   =   array_keys($rates[$rate_id]->taxes);

            $price_excl_tax = $rates[$rate_id]->cost + $dist_cost;
            $rates[$rate_id]->cost =  number_format($price_excl_tax, 2);

            $tax_calculation = $rates[$rate_id]->taxes[$tax_keys[0]] + $dist_cost*(TAX_AMOUNT_IVA-1);
            $rates[$rate_id]->taxes[$tax_keys[0]] = number_format($tax_calculation, 2);

            $rates[$rate_id]->cost +=   $dist_cost;
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

**EDIT**, again

This (mk. ~17786) seems to be in the right direction.
I changed the hook and force `calculate_shipping()` from WC_Shipping

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_before_shipping', 'fty_force_calculate_shipping', 1, 2550 );
function fty_force_calculate_shipping() {
    WC()->shipping->calculate_shipping(WC()->shipping->packages);
    WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
}
```

but it's not perfect yet, i think this hook makes a loop in the checkout page...

Comment: You should better add your custom code related in your question… *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**"*

Comment: @LoicTheAztec i added some *embryo* code i'm trying to understand something more on what's happening...

Comment: Could you add in your question your custom code used in `woocommerce_package_rates` hook, please… It seems that you are using a WC version before v3 … which one?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec woocommerce v2.6.14

Comment: @LoicTheAztec added `woocommerce_package_rates` callback

Answer (score 3):

This needs to be done in `woocommerce_package_rates` only. In your code there is many errors or mistakes… Try the following:

```
function custom_calculated_shipping() {
    return 99.99;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_shipping_rate_cost_calculation', 10, 2 );
function custom_shipping_rate_cost_calculation( $rates, $package ) {
    foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
        if ( 'flat_rate' === $rate->method_id ){

            // Get rate cost and Custom cost
            $initial_cost = $rates[$rate_key]->cost;
            $additional_cost = custom_calculated_shipping();

            // Calculation
            $new_cost = $initial_cost + $additional_cost;

            // Set Custom rate cost
            $rates[$rate_key]->cost = round($new_cost, 2);

            // Taxes rate cost (if enabled)
            $new_taxes = array();
            $has_taxes = false;
            foreach ( $rate->taxes as $key => $tax ){
                if( $tax > 0 ){
                    // Calculating the tax rate unit
                    $tax_rate = $tax / $initial_cost;
                    // Calculating the new tax cost
                    $new_tax_cost = $tax_rate * $new_cost;
                    // Save the calculated new tax rate cost in the array
                    $new_taxes[$key] = round( $new_tax_cost, 2 );
                    $has_taxes = true;
                }
            }
            // Set new tax rates cost (if enabled)
            if( $has_taxes )
                $rate->taxes = $new_taxes;
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Tested and works. It will work in all woocommerce versions since 2.6…

> **You should need to refresh the shipping caches:** 
>   1) First this code is already saved on your function.php file. 
>   2) Empty cart. 
>   3) In **Shipping settings**, enter in a Shipping Zone and disable a **Shipping Method** and "save". Then re-enable that **Shipping Method** and "save". **You are done.**

Comment: Thanx, i tried your code, but it doesn't solve the problem, that's elsewhere, i think. As i wrote in my question `woocommerce_package_rates` callback is called *only* if the user clicks on a shipping method - i'm talking about the cart page, not the checkout page. Gonna updating my answer with mk. 4  :)

Comment: @j.c This hook works everywhere and is the right hook to make customizations on shipping costs… There is not really other ways. So the problem is more in the way you are setting the dynamic cost in it. You should may be use also WC_Sessions for dynamic values…

Comment: WC_Sessions and WC_Shipping are the things i'm looking at, but i'm quite sure that the `woocommerce_package_rate` hook triggers only when user changes shipping method. `WC()->shipping->calculate_shipping(WC()->shipping->packages);` triggers it, but i need to run this in the right place. I'm trying in `woocommerce_cart_totals_before_shipping` hook